# Tarski-vaught and elementary substructure counter example

Tags: logic, model-theory

I had to show that if $\mathcal{A} \leq \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B} \leq \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A} \prec \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{B} \prec \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{B} \prec \mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{A} \prec\mathcal{B}$. It was very easy to show, however I needed to come up with a counter example that the condition $\mathcal{B} \prec \mathcal{C}$ is necessary. A hint was given as take $A = (0,1),B = [0,1]$ and $C = \mathbb{R}$ and apply the Tarski-Vaught Lemma, otherwise known as the Tarski-Vaught condition. I've taken a sequence wlog $a_1 \leq a_2 \cdots \leq a_n$ where all the $a_i$'s are in A = (0,1). By the Tarski-Vaught lemma, $\mathcal{A} \prec \mathcal{C} \iff $ for all formula $\varphi(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$, $\mathcal{C} \models \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \varphi(x,a_1,\cdots,a_n) \implies \mathcal{A} \models \exists y \in (0,1) \varphi(y,a_1,\cdot,a_n) $. But I couldn't carry on any further, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Luckily, if you fix $a_1,...,a_n\in (0,1)$, there is an  (order-) isomorphism $(0,1)\to \Bbb{R}$ that fixes $a_1,...,a_n$. This shows that $(0,1)$ is an elementary substructure of $\Bbb{R}$. It's also easy to see that $(0,1)$ is not an elementary substructure of $[0,1]$ since they're not elementarily equivalent.

Comment: What is a sort of rigorous argument that (0,1) is not an elementary substructure of [0,1] and [0,1] is not a substructure of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: They're not elementarily equivalent: one has a minimum element, and the other does not